# How to call vbscript function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vbscript

I'm new to JQuery. I'm trying to call **vbscript** function **inside jQuery**. I want to call vbscript on button click using jQuery. I tried calling vbscript function  **"callfun()"** using button **onclick()** method of **javascript** for button **"Say Hello"**, and it is working. But when I'm trying to call the same vbscript function **"callfun()"** using **jQuery** for button **"Say MACRO"**. It is showing nothing.

(***THE BELOW CODE REQUIRES ENABLING OF ACTIVEXOBJECTS.***)

> Steps to run the below code:

- Copy and save the below code in notepad and save the file with **.html** extension.
- Open chrome, search for **"IE TAB"** extension or [download](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/activex) from here, install it, and add it to chrome to enable the plugin icon.
- Now open the **.html** file, click on **IE TAB extension**.
- The link or html page will open automatically directly inside the IE TAB plugin and then the html code can be tested.

```html
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/Vbscript">
 Function callfun() 
 Msgbox("Hello!")
 End Function
   </script>
   <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mac").click(function(){
       callfun();
    });
 });
   </script>
   </head> 
   <body>
      <input type = "button" onclick = "callfun()" value = "Say Hello" />
      <input type = "button" id="mac" value = "Say MACRO" />
   </body>
</html>
```

I even tried making changes in the jQuery script as:

*Adding **vbscript** label before the function.*

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#mac").click(function(){
       vbscript:callfun();
    });
  });
</script>
```

*Adding jQuery **attr()** function.*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#mac").attr("onclick", "callfun()");
    });
</script>
```

*Adding **language** in jQuery **attr()** function.*

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#mac").attr("language", "vbscript").attr("onclick", "callfun");
    });
</script>
```

But nothing called the vbscript function using jQuery.
Someone PLEASE help me or suggest me a way to get it done.

Comment: How do you open the HTML file? Why do you need VBS code?

Comment: @omegastripes The above html code can be run using browser extension "IE TAB" (link is shared below). I need to call the existing vbscript on button click in the application which works on jQuery. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en

Comment: Can you explain the bigger picture? What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe you don't need VBScript?

Comment: @Jobbo Basically, I had lot of vbscript codes which I need to reuse it. And I want to execute it (vbscript codes) on a button click using jQuery.

Comment: If you MUST reuse this VBScript rather than re-write it in Javascript, then why attempt to invoke it with JQuery in the first place? Why don't you have a VBScript click handler in the button, since the VBScript is only going to be reusable in IE anyway...

Answer (score 0):

despite the fact you may be using this legitimately its not a 'nice' way to go about doing whatever your trying to do. and most browsers and even windows itself will try its hardest to block what you are doing on multiple levels because security wise this is a very VERY sketchy way of doing whatever your trying to accomplish lol

so the fact this doesnt work does not surprise me. what i would do is to get a packet sniffer running and read all the http data that occours to get clues on if its properly sent out and how server / page responds.

this probably violates the same-orgin policy DOM model of internet rules and stuff or atleast kinda close to violating it, your work is interesting i used to love vbscript but vbscript is becoming rapidly deprecated too

i dont recomend doing this at all: but just for test, you can lower your IE security settings level temporarily. and see if doing that allows sketchy scripts to go through